# Database procedures and functions vs web services

Tags: database, web-services, stored-procedures

In our development team we have:

- 4 developers
- one application uses PHP and database Microsoft SQL Server 2008r2, except one using PowerBuilder instead of PHP and one using MySql instead of Microsoft SQL Server
- All applications are database-centered, some of them are for general public, some are not.

Question is: for the procedures and functions shared by all applications, what does it make most sense to use, database procedures/functions or web services?
We could not find an agreement within the team.

Whatever you answer, please explain the reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webservices and Database Proc/Functions are two entirely different things. 

`Webservices` are the services over the web, mainly used when a client and a server interact and client interacts with the server through web or HTTP or any other protocol.

`Database` proc/func - are created to interact with a login to a DB server.

In your case, if all the application are in the same domain... then you dont need to access through webservices and also it is a lot of overhead.

You can create a common DB server , where you can keep these proc/func and can be consumed by all.